# Converting all columns of dtype 'object' to 'float' in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I wanted to convert all the 'object' type columns to another data type (float) in a dataframe without hard coding the column names. I was able to piece together some code from other answers that seems to work, but I feel like there's got to be a simpler way of doing this.

```
# Creating isolating columns of object data type
object_cols = df.loc[:, df.dtypes == 'O']

# Extracting column names with list comprehension
object_type_columns = [col for col in object_cols.columns]

# Converting column types of .astype in a for loop
for col in object_type_columns:
  df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
```

Let me know if there's any information I'm leaving out (I'm new at this). Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to find the column names:

```
s = df.select_dtypes(include='object').columns
df[s] = df[s].astype("float")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, to convert the whole data frame all at once:

```
df = df.astype('float')
```

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
df.column_name.str.replace(r'\s+','').astype(float)
```

Comment: Maybe, but is has no explanation as to why it is a good solution.

Comment: I was going to ask, what exactly is the regex doing here?

Comment: @KristianCanler is it provides the answer for your question?